# AgrumenNullException in ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: c#, threadpool, argumentnullexception, queueuserworkitem

I've got a method which gets called frequently by different treads. Sometimes I get an AgrumenNullException when `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(display(angebot), null);` gets called, stating that the parameter `callBack` (the first parameter) is null.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ai : UserControl
{
    //...
    public void Display(Angebote angebot)
    {
        lock (_syncObj) { _current = angebot; }
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(display(angebot), null);
    }
    private WaitCallback display(Angebote angebot)
    {
        // doing something
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: It is telling you that your display() method returned null.  Which from the snippet is quite believable, nothing to look at.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry! I add some content later. Currently I'm changing the code, according to the Aanswer of @Chris Sinclair. My method definetly returns `null` like he guessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` will do the work as defined in the `WaitCallback` delegate returned by `display(Angebote)`.  I would surmise that your `display` method sometimes returns null.

Is your intent to execute `display(angebot)` in the background thread, or does that method discern what method should be executed?

If you're thinking that your display method should be executing in a background thread:

```
private WaitCallback display(Angebote angebot)
{
    // doing something in a background thread
}
```

Then your code should look like:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(display, angebot);

private void display(object state)
{
    Angebot angebot = (Angebot)state;
    // doing something in a background thread
}
```

EDIT: If it's the latter where `display` is figuring out what background thread to execute, then perhaps you have something looking like this:

```
private WaitCallback display(Angebote angebot)
{
    if (angebot.Something)
    {
         return new WaitCallback(BackgroundTask1);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But since you haven't posted that code, I'm not sure.  In this case, returning `null` is invalid for `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

Comment: `display` gets called in background, yes ... and may indeed return `null` sometimes. I'll check that.

Comment: Yeah, so this is what I suspected.  With your current code, `display` is _not_ run in a background thread.  You need to modify your code as I suggested before the edit.